# Ubuntu in dualboot. I can't see my wifi anymore but I can see my neighbour's and can use phone hotspot

Tags: networking, connection

Today I switched from my router wifi to my phone's hotspot and I couldn't find my router anymore in the wifi settings. I tried connecting using the hidden network option but it didn't work. I restarted the network manager with `sudo service network-manager restart` but nothing happened. I tried to turn off and on my wifi router but nothing happened. On the other hand, if I boot on Windows I can easily connect to my wifi. I also tried to remove and re-add the connection manually but I still cannot connect to it.
Wireless card: Qualcomm Atheros AR9287
the command: `sudo lspci -k -s 02:00.0` doesn't show me anything

I'm using a 2.4GHz band, my router is set on 2.4GHz

`iwlist freq`:

```
lo        no frequency information.

enp5s0    no frequency information.

wlp3s0    11 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Current Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
```

Update @heynnema:
`iwlist scan | grep -i ssid`

```
lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

enp5s0    Interface doesn't support scanning.

                    ESSID:"Vodafone-A85888772"
                    ESSID:"Vodafone-WiFi"
                    ESSID:"test"
```

The network's name is not showing

The router's channel is set to 13

Comment: Edit your question and show me `iwlist freq`, and tell me if you're using 2.4Ghz or 5Ghz band, and tell me what channel the router is set for in 2.4Ghz and 5Ghz wireless.

Comment: Enabling hotspot on a phone will only add it to the list of wifi ssid's to connect to from the computer with Ubuntu. It will not do what you suggest and cause another ssid to go missing. You must have done something else.

Comment: It looks kind of like you're connecting right now to ch 6. Is Internet not working now? It's a little unclear what the cell phone's hotspot has to do with this. Please explain. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them. Also, remember to ping the user when you update your question with requested info.

Comment: do you have wavemon installed on your pc it can possibly give you some information about your wifi.

Comment: @heynnema it said that I was connected to channel 6 because I was using my phone's hotspot. I don't know if my phone has anything to do with this, but all that happened was that I switched connection once (from my router to my phone) and then I couldn't find my wifi anymore. If I try to connect to my wifi treating it as a hidden network, my PC just notifies me with a connection error.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `iwlist scan | grep -i ssid`. What is the name of the wifi network that you're trying to connect to? In the router, what channel is it set to use?

Comment: @heynnema I don't know if it can help, but I'm using a Qualcomm Atheros AR9287 Network Adapter

Comment: @heynnema thank you very much for your support, now I can connect to my wifi again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments...

```
wlp3s0    11 channels in total; available frequencies :
      Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
      Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
      Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
      Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
      Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
      Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
      Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
      Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
      Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
      Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
      Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
```

The router is set incorrectly. Your wifi card will work on channels 1-11, but your router is set to use channel 13. That won't work.

Set your router to use either channel 1/6/11, and reboot the router. Then everything should work.

You can also load `WiFi Analyzer` on your smart phone, and determine which of those channels is used the least, and then set your router accordingly.

Comment: setting your wifi to the least used channel is good advice not only for the OP but for everybody and it can increase wifi coverage by a lot like 100%+